# Access SCSS variable from TypeScript

Tags: angular, sass

I'm creating a custom directive in Angular. I have a SCSS file with variables, like the image below, which I would like to import to my directive (.directive.ts). How can I do that?

[image: variables.scss]

[image: chip.directive.ts]

Thanks

Comment: would your mind taking the code from the pic and pasting it as text into your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write them to [custom CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) (you can use [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) rule for lists):

```
:root {
  --bs-light: #f1f2f3;
  --bs-dark: #3e3e3c;
}
```

2. Use this code to read variables from the document:

```
export enum ScssVariables {
    Light = "light",
    Dark = "dark",
}

@Directive({
    selector: "[test-attr]",
})
export class TestDirective {
    public styles: { [key in ScssVariables]: string | null } = {
        light: null,
        dark: null,
    };

    constructor() {
        const styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
        Object.keys(this.styles).forEach((key: ScssVariables) => {
            this.styles[key] = styles.getPropertyValue("--bs-" + key);
        })
        console.log(this.styles);
    }
}
```